# didDeselectAnnotationView event firing even when selecting a pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I have two events, one fires on selection of a pin.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view { // when they click on a pin

if([view.annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]] || pinSelected == TRUE) // if its the users location ignore it or if pin already selected
{
    return;
}
    pinSelected = true;
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin_selected.png"]; // change the image to selected
    [self HideShowDetailsMenu:[view.annotation.title integerValue] ShowDetails:true];
}
```

which changes the pin to selected and makes a details menu appear with data relating to the selected pin and another which fires on deselecting a pin

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view { // when they click off a pin    

if([view.annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]] || pinSelected == FALSE) // if its the users location ignore it or if pin already selected
    return;

NSLog(@"This is running");
if ([view.annotation.subtitle integerValue] ==  [AppConstants Instance].CurrentStore.storeid)
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin_starred.png"]; // set the pin to the unselected image
else
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin_unselected.png"]; // change the pin to unselected 

pinSelected = false;
[self HideShowDetailsMenu:[view.annotation.title integerValue] ShowDetails:false]; // pin unselected so hide the details menu

}
```

which will happen when a user deselects a Pin on the MapView.

However my issue that is occuring is that when I select a pin that has already been selected my program crashes, I am trying to circumvent this by implementing a bool that is set to true if a pin is set, which will just 'return' and do nothing if the event is triggered again.

However my issue is that the 'didDeselectAnnotationView' event will trigger when I select a pin that has been selected, even though I am not deselecting a pin at all. This triggers the 'pinSelected' variable to be set to false, then the 'didSelectAnnotationView' even is triggered which with the 'pinSelected' variable set to false will then run again crashing the program.

Have I done something wrong? What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
    {
        indexPathTag=aView.tag;
        [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES];

    }
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView
    {
    }
```

When didSelectAnnotationView fires, it actually tags the annotation as selected somehow. Then when you click it again, the delegate function doesn't fire because it is 'already selected'. You have to manually deselect the annotation by calling the following function once you're done doing what you want.
So you have to Add [mapView deselectAnnotation:aView.annotation animated:YES]; in didSelectAnnotationView delegate method.